# Add secondary public IP to Sonicwall NSA 3500

Tags: firewall, sonicwall

I have a Sonicwall NSA 3500 firewall. I have a primary block of public IP addresses that are working fine but I need to utilize a second block of IPs that are routing over the primary from the telco side.  Does anyone know how to configure this on a sonic wall? I am not finding much info on it.
I have done the NATing and firewall rules etc but I don't see a place to configure the gateway on the firewall for the 2nd block of IPs.

Comment: Just to clarify and simplify, you have two different, non-sequential blocks of IP addresses coming in over a single connection to the ISP correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this knowledge base article](https://support.software.dell.com/kb/sw7621) for details, but basically:

1. Create a Static ARP entry for the new network.
2. Create a Static Route

Comment: This link no longer points to a specific article.

Comment: I've updated it, David.

Answer (score -1):

Needed to add a static arp entry and static route for 2nd set of public IP addresses.

Comment: Please click the check mark to select an answer.  See the FAQ for details.